# when stopping twisted, will the factory wait the sql execution done?

Tags: python, twisted, kill

I wonder if I stop the twistd process using

```
kill `cat twistd.pid`
```

What will happen if there are exactly some sql execution committing?
Will it waiting for the execution done? or just unknown, it could be done, or abandon?

I know if I put the execution in the **stopFactory** method, the factory will do such things like waiting for the execution done. But if I don't, I mean the execution out the stopFactory method, will it waiting for the execution done before the factory stopping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

kill sends `SIGTERM` by default.  Twisted installs a `SIGTERM` handler which calls `reactor.stop()`.  Anything that would happen when you call `reactor.stop()` will happen when you use that `kill` command.

More specifically, any shutdown triggers will run.  This means any services attached to an `Application` will have their `stopService` method called (and if a `Deferred` is returned, it will be allowed to finish before shutdown proceeds).  It also means worker threads in the reactor threadpool will be shutdown in an orderly manner - ie, allowed to complete whatever job they have in progress.

If you're using adbapi, then the `ConnectionPool` uses its own `ThreadPool` and also registers a shutdown trigger to shut that pool down in a similar orderly manner.

So, when you use `kill` to stop a Twisted-based process, any SQL mid-execution will be allowed to complete before shutdown takes place.

Comment: I'm using adbapi, so I think it's safe. Thanks, JP.